# Multiplatform solution to view pdf files in Emacs

Tags: microsoft-windows, pdf

I'm searching for solution for viewing .pdf files in Emacs on both Linux and Windows platform.

Here is list of my requirements:

- Outline (view, use to navigate)
- Follow links
- Search text

Basically I'm searching for alternative to [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) since `pdf-tools` does not support windows platform atm.

Functionality I'm searching for can be seen in following gif
[image]

and in [this video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2bc1is_pdf-tools-tourdeforce_tech?forcedQuality%3Dhd720) which show even more functionality than I desire.

Comment: The `doc-view-mode` not cross-platform?

Comment: @PythonNut To the best of my knowledge, `doc-view-mode` is missing features described in question.

Comment: No, there are no alternatives to doc-view and pdf-tools for viewing PDFs in Emacs.  Either you live with he limitations of the former or you port pdf-tools to Windows (which doesn't seem to require much [work](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/54#issuecomment-103166225)).

Comment: The question should be reopened, after editting it is clearly related to emacs. And it is answerable, since an answer has been given in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

pdf-tools says:

```
Other operating systems are currently not supported (patches welcome)
```

so your best option is to get pdf-tools to work on Windows.  I don't see any technical reason why this should be difficult.